# Insert Views into TextView Programmatically

Tags: android, parsing, hyperlink, textview

I'm setting up a parsing system where I read the content inside a TextView and create a view for each of the links discovered within the text. Currently, I have a linearlayout with the inflated views below the textview. How could I move these views INTO the textview directly underneath the content that was linked?

For example, I have two links here:

> Link #1
>
> Link #2

and below I have

> [Link #1 bubble] [Link #2 bubble]

I'm trying to get it to look like this

> Link #1
>
> [Link #1 bubble]
>
> Link #2
>
> [Link #2 bubble]

## EDIT

there aren't two separate TextViews. There is one TextView with two lines of text!

Example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to do this. I would do it this way, assuming you use a Layout file for your View:

1. Use a relative layout and position a transparent imageview OVER your text view.
2. Align the imageview's right side with the TextView's right side and the top and bottom of the imageview with the TextView's top and bottom. This bounds it to the right side of the text view and contains it within the textview.
3. Default the view to visibility to GONE.
4. When you have something, set the imageview to the content and change the visibility.

Some gotcha's:
1. Because the image view is ONTOP of the textview, it can cause interaction issues with the textview.
2. You could put the ImageView behind the TextView, but you'd have to play with transparency of the text view. This would help with #1.

Some psuedo sample code of the Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/bubble" android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv" android:layout_alignRight="@id/tv" android:visibility="gone" ...>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hmm, the thing is the text is static, so it's not actually two TextViews. It's one line of text in one textview that is spaced out to two lines.

Comment: You can add offsets to the imageview. It is tough to visualize what you want, can you provide a screenshot instead?

Comment: Ah, I see, I was thinking EditText also, I was quite confused. Why not generate HTML content and dump it to the textview, or better yet, use a webview?

Comment: I don't control the backend so I have to do parsing on my own on the frontend. It comes to me as formatted HTML, with links already wrapped. All I can do is parse the links and find out what kind of content it is, and display it. Currently it's displayed below for me but I want to display it inline. I also intend to have the ability to disable the feature so that wouldn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Hmm.. well I do not think a TextView is appropriate for what you want. I don't see why using a webview is different from a textview in this case. You still parse your content, get the image, create programmatically the HTML content and instead of a textview use a webview to dump the generated HTML to.

Comment: The issue with that is I'll be opening activities when the user clicks on the linked content. It also has to interface with my app font settings and themes, which would not be possible with a WebView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83574/discussion-between-cookster-and-ccrama).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can set it like this

```
    TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    textView.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.image);
```

You can also specify Uri if you don't have that image in drawable

**UPDATED**
To create that textview as a link you can do something like that

```
Linkify.addLinks(textView,Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: The issue is there could be dozens of items that I need to display inline with the text, and I dont know what kind of content it might be. If I have a link to google.com/blah, I need to show a link icon and the text, "google.com" to give the user context on what they are clicking.

Comment: I get it but if you just want a link and image it will work

Comment: It will be more than images, it will also parse text (find lines that start with x), so that won't work. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use a multiple textview system. I will split the content string at the points I'm inserting data, and put the inflated view between the two textviews. Hopefully that will do it for me!